# How to deal with the stored procedure's return value in MVC3?

Tags: stored-procedures

I am trying to get the return value which comes from the store procedure.

```
SP :csp_storeprocedure returns (int a, int b, int c,)
```

I aleady imported this funcion and set return type to Complex.

However, I really do not know how to get the return value from the store procedure.

How can I do this?

Comment: How does MVC involved in this?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
YourComplexType someVar = yourContextName.StoredProcName(anyParams);
```

Your context name maybe 'WhateverEntities' - depends what you named it when creating the edmx model, etc.